# Why char array doesnt work in dynamic struct array?

Tags: arrays, struct

Im trying to learn about structures in c++. I want to make a dynamic structures array, initialize it with some values and then view this values on the screen. Why does it work when using string and doesnt while using char array.

```
#include <iostream>

struct batonik
{
char name[20];
double weight;
int calories;
};

int main()
{
batonik *ps = new batonik[3]
{
    { "snickers",2.2,350 },
    { "mars",2.6,420 },
    { "bounty",2.1,210 }
};
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    std::cout << "Nazwa batonika : " << (*(ps+i)).name << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Waga batonika : " << (ps+i)->weight << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Ilosc kalorii : " << (ps+i)->calories<< std::endl;
    std::cout << i;
}
delete [] ps;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: what means it doesn't work for char array.It works for me but why not you?

Comment: It return random numbers and lines without any text in the place of name

Comment: I complied the code in "code blocks" it works perfectly.